# Do "service ntpd restart" and "ntpdate <ntp-server-ip>" do the same work?

Tags: ntp, ntpd, ntpdate

I often get large offsets when checking `ntpd` using `ntpq -p`, I generally restart the ntp daemon and it fixes the issue. I wanted to know if i can try the `ntpdate <ntp-server-name>` instead of restarting `ntpd`. Since this is a production box wanted to be sure before implementing it.

Comment: Having a large offset regularly is not normal and if configured correctly, `ntpd` should prevent this.

Comment: Large offsets can be generated by `ntpd` itself via the kernel clock discipline if the clock is unexpectedly reset while it's running. For example, by using `ntpdate` or even `date --set ...`

Answer (score 3):

`ntpdate` and `ntpd` are different tools, but one of them helps another.

`ntpdate` is used to synchronize the system clock at once immediately. It takes time from a `ntpd` server, which has synchronized status (stratum 1 - 4).

`ntpd` service sets system clock **softly**. It can spend several hours to eliminate the lag of system clock for several minutes. All this time it has synchronized status `stratum 16` - it means the system clock isn't synchronized. The service restart command `service ntpd restart` is used only to apply changes in its configuration file.

`ntpdate` is usually used to synchronize the system clock of personal computer at startup. `ntpd` service is usually used to synchronize the system clock of  server all-time.

Comment: `ntpd` is often set to step the clock at system startup. Its biggest advantage over `ntpdate` is that it understands about clock drift and compensates for that over time.

Comment: Please. Look for default ubuntu desktop dhcp-client config `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/ntpdate` and dhcp option `DHCP option 42 Network Time Protocol Servers`.

Answer (score 2):

No. Citing `man ntpdate`:

> ntpdate  will  decline  to set the date if an NTP server daemon (e.g., ntpd) is running on the same host. When
>          running ntpdate on a regular basis from cron as an alternative to running a daemon, doing so once  every  hour
>          or two will result in precise enough timekeeping to avoid stepping the clock.

Answer (score 1):

On various commonly-used Linux distributions (including CentOS, Debian, and Ubuntu), `ntpd` is started with the `-g` flag by default, which means it will perform a large clock step on the first adjustment if needed.  So for the majority of cases, `ntpdate` shouldn't be needed, and restarting `ntpd` would be preferred.

But, as Sven commented, if `ntpd` has been running for a while and you still end up with a large offset, then something's wrong with your NTP setup or your network (or both).

So rather than restarting `ntpd` or running `ntpdate`, try diagnosing why you end up in this situation in the first place.

Some common issues:

1. Not including enough peers - you should have [at least 4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-ntp-bcp-06#section-4.1).  Read through the whole BCP draft if you have the time.
2. Using the `server` with the [public NTP pool](http://www.pool.ntp.org/) instead of the newer `pool` directive - you should use the latter if your `ntpd` supports it.
3. Using peers which are too far away or poorly connected - try to select close-by, reliable peers.  Even better, augment your external peers with a local reference clock for your network.  (A BeagleBone, Raspberry Pi, or LeoNTP with a GPS receiver might be a good choice, depending on your environment.)
4. There might be other reasons why your server is struggling to keep good time, such as a [kernel bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1759787) or poor hardware clock.  Enabling `loopstats`, `peerstats`, and `sysstats` in your `ntp.conf` should help to track this down.

Post your configuration and the output from `ntpq -np` and hopefully we should be able to help you work this out.